# Flutter on Android Studio - Intellisense not working

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin

I have a Flutter project and I have to write a specific code platform (android), but when I open the android app folder and go to the kotlin folder to create my activity/service, the IDE does not recognize the extension and does not suggest the imports and neither complete the code. Does anyone knows how to solve this? I tried on Android Studio Gartic, but without success I did the downgrade to Android Studio 3.5